# Wrapping unmanaged code

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper

Where I'm currently working, they have a lot of unmanaged C++. The written C++ has a LOT of memory management. They manage their own memory like that. It also uses a lot of MFC, instead of .NET Framework stuff.

My question is: Could I import this code into C# using Wrapper classes of some kind? Or does it have to be Managed and/or .NET Framework code that can be wrapped like that?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: you would have to write a c++/cli wrapper library.

Comment: Yes you can.  In fact it does not make sense to wrap managed C++.  It's already .NET compatible, so by definition a wrapper is a something around unmanaged code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import the code by properly referencing it and by using the following flags for the method calling the code:

[SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction::LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag::UnmanagedCode)]